# new Date can't give me right time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, slice

```
startDate = "2019-03-07 (목) 12:00";

var year = startDate.slice(0,4);
var month = startDate.slice(5,7);
var day = startDate.slice(8,10);
var hour = startDate.slice(15,17);
var minute = startDate.slice(18,20);

var selEndDatetime = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
console.log(selEndDatetime);
```

I want to see "Tue Mar 07 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)", but console shows me the message "Sun Apr 07 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)".

What is wrong this code and how can I modify it to get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The month starts at 0. You need to parse month from string to integer and minus 1 when creating a date instance.

```js
startDate = "2019-03-07 (목) 12:00";

var year = startDate.slice(0,4);
var month = parseInt(startDate.slice(5,7))
var day = startDate.slice(8,10);
var hour = startDate.slice(15,17);
var minute = startDate.slice(18,20);

var selEndDatetime = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute);
console.log(selEndDatetime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the `startDate` string as an argument to the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in order to create `selEndDatetime`

Code:

```js
const startDate = '2019-03-07 (목) 12:00';
const selEndDatetime = new Date(startDate);

console.log(selEndDatetime);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's very simple!